# I need to split up one file with many trajectories into individual files

Tags: perl

I have a file called Au7.ANI that has the following format:

[image]

Everytime a number 37 appears up as a header it means it is a new set of coordinates that follow it. This is repeated in the file 2,000 times.

What I want to do is split this file into many files by adding the 37 at the top of every file with it's respective set of xyz coordinates that follow it.

This should produce 2,000 files since there are 2,000 individual xyz coordinates in that file.

How can I do this and have every file named coord.xyz_1, coord.xyz_2, etc until coord.xyz_2000?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd probably reach for `csplit` rather than perl: it's hard to give a precise (tested) answer since *you posted a png image of your file instead of actual text*, but something like `csplit -f 'coord.xyz_' -b '%d' file '/^[[:space:]]*37$/' '{*}'`

Comment: @steeldriver It sounds like you may wish to post that as an answer so the asker can accept it as an answer.  (And so they can mark this as resolved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably reach for csplit rather than perl: it's hard to give a precise (tested) answer since you posted a png image of your file instead of actual text, but something like

```
csplit -f 'coord.xyz_' -b '%d' yourfile '/^[[:space:]]*37$/' '{*}'
```

where

- `-f 'coord.xyz_'` sets the output filename prefix
- `-b '%d'` sets the output numeric suffix format to unpadded decimal digits
- the regular expression `/^[[:space:]]*37$/` matches `37` optionally preceded by whitespace
- `{*}` says to repeat the previous pattern as many times as possible

Note that the regular expression could possibly be simplified based on the actual content of your file: for example, if the `37` marker is always indented by a single tab, you could reduce it to `/^\t37$/`.

---

If you want to implement something equivalent in perl (as per your tag), then based on this suggestion [How can I split a text file into multiple text files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46349/65304) you could try

```
perl -ne 'open(F, ">", "coord.xyz_".++$n) if /[[:space:]]*37/; print F;' yourfile
```